# What is Space and Time Complexity of this particular code

Tags: python, time, space

String compression

```
def com(s):
count = {}
char = []
fianl = []
for i in s:
    if i not in count:
        count[i] = 1

    else:
        count[i] +=1
#return count
for i ,j  in count.items():
    char.append(i)
    char.append(j)
for i in char:
    fianl.append(str(i))

return "".join(fianl)


s = "AAAAABBBBCCCC"
print(com(s))
```

2nd it is to find if all characters in string is unique or not

```
def uniq_c(s):
count = {}
for i in s:
    if i not in count:
        count[i] = 1
    else:
        count[i] +=1
#return count
for i in count.values():
    if i != 1:
        return False
return True


ar = "abcdee"
print(uniq_c(ar))
```

Just wanted to know if it is of O(n) or not?
or any other suggestion if its not
Thanks

Comment: Do you have some thoughts on your own or do you just want the solution presented to you?

Comment: @timgeb I've tried

Answer (score 0):

The average time complexity of fetching data from any dictionary(hash table) is O(1), and worst time complexity will be O(n) which is a very rare case based on the history of containers. Hence, it is generally treated as O(1) time complexity. Rest of the code complexity is very obvious.

Read this [official link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for reference.

Given this, you can deduce the complexity yourself now.